# How to control camera lens by Arduino's PWM? What FOCUS A+, FOCUS A- wires means?

Tags: pwm

I have a camera lens which I want to control by arduino (like this https://vi.aliexpress.com/item/1005004141070063.html)

I have an info about wires description but I can't understand what focus A+, A-, B+, B- means? I guess I need to send PWM pulses to A and B wires to move focus in straigt and opposite direction but I can't understand what + and - means. Is it just signal and ground?

[image: Manual]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you will be dealing with bipolar stepper motors. Most
likely, A+ and A− are connected to one coil, whereas B+ and B− are
connected to the other coil.

See the Arduino documentation: [Arduino and Stepper Motor
Configurations](https://docs.arduino.cc/learn/electronics/stepper-motors) for instructions on driving this kind of motor.